# IBM DB2 Backup restore on windows - DB2 version 9.7

Tags: db2

**I have offline backup of IBM DB2 database, Which I am trying to restore using the following command.**

[image]

**It is throwing following error**  [image]

Is there any problem in the command.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems, actually. First, in the `from` clause you must specify the directory enclosing the backup image, not the image itself. The second problem is the spaces in the directory name. Thirdly, it's `taken at`, not `takenat`.

I have no way of testing this on Windows, but you may want to try enclosing the `from` path in double quotes:

```
db2 restore db exoffice from "d:\db2\offline backup - db2hc" taken at ...
```